# Выдает ошибку почему?

Tags: php

admin.php

```
<?php
include('./lib.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $auth = trim($_POST['auth']);
    $ganr = trim($_POST['ganr']);
    $discp = trim($_POST['discp']);
    $price = trim($_POST['price']);
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    if (!$link){
        die("Не могу соединиться с базой данных");
    }else {
    mysql_select_db('catalog',$link);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO books(name,author,genre,description,price) VALUES ('$name','$auth','$ganr','$discp','$price')",$link);
    }
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center"><h1>Add book</h1></div>
<form method="POST" action="admin.php">
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Название</td>
<td valing="top"><input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Автор</td>
<td valing="top"><input name="auth" type="text" value="" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Жанр</td>
<td valing="top"><input name="ganr" type="text" value="" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Описание </td>
<td valing="top"><textarea name="discp" cols="22"
rows="10"  > </textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Цена </td>
<td valing="top"><input name="price" type="text" value="" size="30"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div align="center">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Очистить" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</div>
<br>
<div align="center"><h1>Editing book</h1></div>
<?
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("catalog",$link);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name, author, genre, description, price FROM books ORDER BY name ");
if($count = 0){
    echo "Не найдено ни одной записи";
} else {
    print("<form method=\"post\">");
                    print("<table border=\"2\" align=\"center\">");
                    print("<tr>");
                    print("<td>Name</td><td>Author</td><td>Genre</td><td>Description</td><td>Price</td>");
                    print("<td>Delete</td>");
                    print("<td>Update</td>");
                    print("</tr>");
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        print ("<tr>");
                        $aName1 = $row['name'];
                        $aName2 = $row['author'];
                        $aName3 = $row['genre'];
                        $aName4 = $row['description'];
                        $aName5 = $row['price'];
                        $aName6 = $row['id'];
                        print("<td>$aName1</td>");
                                                print("<td>$aName2</td>");
                                                print("<td>$aName3</td>");
                        print("<td>$aName4</td>");
                        print("<td>$aName5</td>");
                        print("<td>");
                        print("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delete[]\" value=\"$aName6\">");  
                        print("</td>");
                        print("<td>");
                        print("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"update[]\" value=\"$aName6\">");  
                        print("</td>");
                        print("</tr>");
                                }
                            print("</table>");
                            print("<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"Delete\">");
                            print("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Update\" value=\"Select Update\"></div>");
                            print("</form>");
                    }
            $data=new DataBase();

        if($_POST['Update']){
if($_POST['update']){
        $data->SelectUpdateRecord();
            }
                    }

    if($_POST['Delete']){
                            if($_POST['delete']){
                                        foreach($_POST['delete'] as $val){
                                        $data->DeleteRecord($val);
                                        }
                            }
                        }

        if($_POST['OkUpdate']){
                    $aS1=0;

foreach($_POST['name'] as $val1){
                    $Email[]=$val1;
                    $aS1++;
                }
foreach($_POST['author'] as $val2){
                    $Name[]=$val2;
                }
foreach($_POST['genre'] as $val3){
                    $Text[]=$val3;
                }
foreach($_POST['description'] as $val4){
                    $Data[]=$val4;
                }
foreach($_POST['price'] as $val5){
                    $Nomer[]=$val5;
                }
foreach($_POST['id'] as $val6){
                    $Nomer[]=$val6;
                }

for($count=0;$count<$aS1;$count++){
$data->UpdateRecord($ID[$count],$Name[$count],$Author[$count],$Genre[$count],$Description[$count],$Price[$count]);
header("Location:admin.php");
                }

                    }
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

lib.php

```
<?php
class DataBase {
    function UpdateRecord($aNomer1,$aNomer2,$aNomer3,$aNomer4,$aNomer5,$aNomer6){
        $aSQL="update books set name='$aNomer1',author='$aNomer2',";
        $aSQL.="genre='$aNomer3',decription='$aNomer4',price='$aNomer5' where id=$aNomer6";
        $aDBLink=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!empty($aDBLink)){
            if(mysql_select_db("catalog",$aDBLink)==True){
            $aQResult=mysql_query($aSQL,$aDBLink);
                if($aQResult==TRUE){
                    } else { print("ERROR Update Record!<br>");}
                        mysql_free_result($aQResult);
                                }
        }
    }
}

function DeleteRecord($aNomer){
    $aDBLink=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!empty($aDBLink)){
        if(mysql_select_db("catalog",$aDBLink)==True){
            $aSQL="delete from books where nomer=$aNomer";
            $aQResult=mysql_query($aSQL,$aDBLink);
                if($aQResult==TRUE){
                        } else { print("ERROR Record No Delete!<br>");}
                mysql_free_result($aQResult);
                }}
                    }
 function SelectUpdateRecord(){
            $aSQL="select * from books where id=";
            $aCOUNT=count($_POST['update']);
            $aNEXT=0;
            foreach($_POST['update'] as $val){
                $aSQL.="$val";
                $aNEXT++;
                if($aNEXT<$aCOUNT){
                $aSQL.=" or id=";
                          }
                              }
                $aDBLink=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!empty($aDBLink)){
                if(mysql_select_db("catalog",$aDBLink)==True){
                $aQResult=mysql_query($aSQL,$aDBLink);
                if($aQResult==TRUE){
                            print("<form method=\"post\">");
                            print("<table border=\"2\">");
                            print("<tr>");
                            print("<td>Name</td><td>Author</td><td>Genre</td><td>Description</td><td>Price</td>");
                            print("<td>Id</td>");
                            print("</tr>");

    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($aQResult);
    while($aRow=mysql_fetch_array($aQResult)){
                            $aName1=$aRow["name"];
                            $aName2=$aRow["author"];
                            $aName3=$aRow["genre"];
                            $aName4=$aRow["description"];
                            $aName5=$aRow["price"];
                            $aName6=$aRow["id"];
                            print("<tr>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\" value=\"$aName1\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"author[]\" value=\"$aName2\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"genre[]\" value=\"$aName3\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"description[]\" value=\"$aName4\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"price[]\" value=\"$aName5\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id[]\" value=\"$aName5\"></td>");
                            print("</tr>");
                        }
                            print("</table>");
                            print("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"OkUpdate\" value=\"Update Ok!\">");
                            print("</form>");
                            }
                                        }
                     }
                    }

?>
```

Comment: Хотя бы написали, что за ошибку и где. А то тупо смотреть код на наличие всего, чего угодно, - это просто маразм. -1 вам и от меня тоже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class DataBase {
    function UpdateRecord($aNomer1,$aNomer2,$aNomer3,$aNomer4,$aNomer5,$aNomer6){
        $aSQL="update books set name='$aNomer1',author='$aNomer2',";
        $aSQL.="genre='$aNomer3',decription='$aNomer4',price='$aNomer5' where id=$aNomer6";
        $aDBLink=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!empty($aDBLink)){
            if(mysql_select_db("catalog",$aDBLink)==True){
            $aQResult=mysql_query($aSQL,$aDBLink);
                if($aQResult==TRUE){
                    } else { print("ERROR Update Record!<br>");}
                        mysql_free_result($aQResult);
                                }
        }
    }
   // }
```

эту скобочку убрать и переместить туда где действительно заканчиваются методы класса. сейчас класс заканчивается UpdateRecord, соответственно SelectUpdateRecord является обычной функцией и никак не методом класса.

Answer (score 4):

0) Учитесь задавать вопросы!
1)

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Эта строка должна быть ДО проверки, подробно расписанной в пункте 2)

2)

```
//if($count = 0){
```

было так. Эта строка присваивает $count значение 0. После чего проверяет. Грубо говоря, она аналогично следующей конструкции:

```
$count = 0;  
if(0){
```

Надо так:

```
if($count == 0){
    echo "Не найдено ни одной записи";
```

3)

```
if(isset($_POST['Update']) && $_POST['Update']){  
if(isset($_POST['Delete']) && $_POST['Delete']){  
if(isset($_POST['OkUpdate']) && $_POST['OkUpdate']){
```

Вот так правильно, вы же не знаете есть этот апдейт или его нет?!

Comment: Выдает вот эту ошибку:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DataBase::SelectUpdateRecord() in Z:\home\localhost\www\practica\admin\admin.php on line 100

Answer (score 0):

я бы добавил что помимо трима надо еще mysql_real_escape_string ставить ну и если необходимо то еще htmlspecialchars а вопроса тож не понял